# Make sublime auto-insert semicolon after colon in SCSS files just like it does with CSS?

Tags: css, sublime-text-3, snippets

Sublime auto-inserts a semicolon after typing a colon in CSS files, but not in SCSS files. I would like this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Go to, Preferences > Browse Packages
Then open

```
Ruby Haml.tmLanguage inside the Rails folder
```

then paste this code to it,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"   
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>fileTypes</key>
<array>
    <string>haml</string>
</array>
<key>foldingStartMarker</key>
<string>^\s*([-%#\:\.\w\=].*)\s$</string>
<key>foldingStopMarker</key>
<string>^\s*$</string>
...
```

Comment: I don't have a Rails folder there. I have the following folders: Autoprefixer, bz2, ColorPicker, PyV8, User.

Comment: sorry, this helped me. I have no idea about your system.